# Calculate Area of Triangle Recursively

Tags: recursion, area

This is a question from a past paper. I am doing an exam on Monday and I am expecting a question like this to come up. Could any one help me answer it?

---

Suppose you are asked to calculate the area of a triangle recursively. Figure III.1 shows
the computerized approximation of the first five shapes. In this figure one square represents one square unit. Notice that the area depends on the width of the triangle.

```
                                          []
                               []        [][]
                     []       [][]      [][][]      Figure III.1
           []       [][]     [][][]    [][][][]
  []      [][]     [][][]   [][][][]  [][][][][]
width=1  width=2   width=3   width=4    width=5
```

Figure III.1 Computerized approximation of a triangular shape.
a) What is the base case for the recursive calculation of the area?
[ 1 mark ]
b) Derive the recursive formula to calculate the area in terms of given “width”.
 HINT: Think about the area difference between the consecutive “width” values.
[ 3 marks ]

---

I am pretty sure the answer to part (a) is:

```
if(width == 0)  
    return 0;
```

But I have no idea how to answer part (b) and in turn part (c).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the post messed up my triangles :/ i am having a bad day.

Comment: What is the difference between area(0) and area(1)? Between area(4) and area(5)? Between area(n) and area(n+1)?

Answer (score 0):

So for every unit of witdh you have your width decreases one by one until it reaches 0.

Well this is not tested but it should be something like this I believe.

```
int CalculateArea(int width, int area)
{
      if(width == 0)
          return area;
      area = area + width;
      return CalculateArea(width - 1, area);

}
```

And when you call the function don't forget to give area 0 first

```
int Width = 5;
int area = CalculateArea(Width, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like area of triangle with width "n" is just: n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1:

And in pseudo code:

```
function foo(int n) {
    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    else { return n + foo(n-1); }
}
```

Comment: Won't this always return 0 since you are returning 0 every time n is 0 and when it is sure to be 0?

Comment: change n to 1 and return 1